# how can I input words and image in the textview?

Tags: ios, textview, core-text

I want to make a view(may be textview) can let me input words and image like emotion. Is there any way? I heard about DTRichTextEditor but it seem not cheap.

Comment: Who asked you to pay for the opensource project ?

Answer (score 0):

why not use a UIWebView and load the contents as HTML.Then use real image `<img>` tags to represent the emoticons.

Another way is to use UILabel for each emoticon and set its background to the image using something like:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"emoticon"]];
```

Trying to put images into UItextView will surely involve hacking which might introduce crashes   into your app with ios version changes.

I hope this helps!

Comment: How are you going to allow a user input with `UILabel` or pure `UIWebView` ? The latter seems reasonable with a lot of javascript only.

Comment: as @A-Live said, I think it is a problem that how to make lable(or DTCoreText) looks like textview.